# Ball Animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, resize, paintcomponent, jcomponent

The Problem is when I resize the `JFrame` the animation goes on with it's Pre supplied dimensions for `JComponent` . Is there a way that I can update my `width` and `height` variables as I resize the `JFrame`, so that the Animation can run along with the new Co-ordinates.

In simpler terms, say the `JComponent` has initial `width = 300` and `height = 300`, so the `BALL` moves inside these specified `Co-ordinates`. Now if I resize my `JFrame`, the size for the `JComponent` still remains as is i.e. `width = 300` and `height = 300`, but what I was hoping for, is a way to modify these variables with the present size of the window. Do let me know if I lack something in explaining my issue.

Here is the code that I am using :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BallAnimation
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int count;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int speedValue;
    private boolean flag;
    /*
     * These variables are used to keep track of 
     * the ball, either it is going LEFT or RIGHT
     * depending on that, we will set the 
     * Co-ordinates.
     */
    private boolean toLeft, toRight;

    private boolean fromTop, fromBottom;

    private Timer timer;

    private JButton button;

    private ActionListener actionTimer; 
    private ActionListener buttonAction;

    public BallAnimation()
    {
        x = y = count = 0;
        flag = toLeft = false;
        toRight = true;
        fromTop = true;
        fromBottom = false;
        speedValue = 5;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                BallAnimation animation = new BallAnimation();
                animation.go();
            }
        };      
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        /*
         * Class Name : 
         * Java Naming Convention says that class names 
         * should be in Pascal Case, i.e. the first
         * letter of the class name should be capitalized
         * and every new word must start with a capitalized 
         * Alphabet.
         * For Example : 
         * public class ClassName{...}
         * ----------------------------------------------------------
         * Variable Name : 
         * Java Naming Convention says that the variable name
         * should be in Camel Case, i.e. the first letter of 
         * the variable name should be small case or _ (underscore)
         * and every new word must start with a capitalized
         * Alphabet.
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */
        final MyDraw drawPanel = new MyDraw(0, 0);
        x = drawPanel.getXValue();
        y = drawPanel.getYValue();
        //contentPane.add(drawPanel);

        actionTimer = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {               
                if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < width && y < height 
                            && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < width && y >= height
                                 && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP LEFT Side
                     * touched the BOTTOM of the JPanel.
                     */
                    y -= speedValue;
                    x += speedValue;
                    fromTop = false;
                    fromBottom = true;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < width && y <= 0
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from BOTTOM LEFT Side
                     * touched the TOP of the JPanel. 
                     */
                    fromTop = true;
                    fromBottom = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < width && y < height
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    x += speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x >= width && y < height
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM LEFT Side
                     * touched the RIGHT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = false;
                    toLeft = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }                
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < width && y <= 0
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM RIGHT Side
                     * touched the Top Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    fromTop = true;
                    fromBottom = false;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x <= 0 && y < height
                                 && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP RIGHT Side
                     * touched the LEFT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = true;
                    toLeft = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x >= width && y < height
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP LEFT Side
                     * touched the RIGHT Side of the JPanel
                     */
                    toRight = false;
                    toLeft = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < width && y < height
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x <= 0 && y < height
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM RIGHT Side
                     * touched the LEFT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = true;
                    toLeft = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < width && y < height
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < width && y >= height
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP RIGHT Side
                     * touched the BOTTOM Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    fromTop = false;
                    fromBottom = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                System.out.println("X : " + x);
                System.out.println("Y : " + y);
                System.out.println("Direction is LEFT : " + toLeft);
                System.out.println("Direction is RIGHT : " + toRight);
                System.out.println("Coming from TOP : " + fromTop);
                System.out.println("Coming from BOTTOM : " + fromBottom);
                drawPanel.setXYValues(x, y);
            }
        };

        buttonAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (!flag)
                {
                    timer.start();
                    button.setText("STOP ANIMATION");
                    flag = true;
                }
                else if (flag)
                {
                    timer.stop();
                    button.setText("START ANIMATION");
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        };

        button = new JButton("START ANIMATION");
        button.addActionListener(buttonAction);

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);        

        timer = new Timer(40, actionTimer);
        width = drawPanel.getWidth() - 30;
        System.out.println("WIDTH : " + width);
        height = drawPanel.getHeight() - 30;    
        System.out.println("HEIGHT : " + height);
    }
    class MyDraw extends JComponent
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private Timer timer;

        public MyDraw(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getXValue()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public int getYValue()
        {
            return y;
        }

        public void setXYValues(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            repaint();
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return (new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that your massive amount of if logic could be compressed into like 1/4 that size, and far less code, right?  Making it use x and y velocities (which could be negative) would eliminate the boolean flags, turn all of the movement code into `x+=xVel;y+=yVel;`, and then you're just left with the out-of-bounds checking, which pushes the ball back within bounds, and inverts the relevant velocity.

Comment: @zebediah49 : May you please ellaborate that logic thingy to me a bit more in your answer :-)

Comment: It's around a 7 year old piece of code, so the graphics handling is rather deprecated.  None the less, the control and wall logic is standard.  It's as long as it is because it has both solid (bounce) and periodic (!bounce) boundary conditions.  http://pastebin.com/UT8fyAaB

Comment: during resize of parent must be Swing Timer inactive, or to held last known Dimension +1

Comment: @zebediah49  Fun code!  Those warnings can be fixed in a few lines of code.  So I did fix them and added a new paste.  ;)

Comment: @mKorbel : THankyou for this info, about turning the Timer off during resize, this question just cleared as to where I should be putting the code to stop the Timer :-)

Comment: You might also enjoy this [`KineticModel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel), which uses a `ComponentListener`.

Comment: @trashgod : Wow, that's amazing, Seems like you have an example for every situation, hehe, too good :-) Thankyou for sharing this link :-) LOL making a single ball I thought, I did something great, but in that link, LOL too many of them, seems like I have to learn too much :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that is a whole heapin' helping of code!  Try this variant (breaks one or two things, but fixes the main problem).  The fix is to base the width/height on the current size of the component.

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BallAnimation
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int count;
    //private int drawPanel.getWidth();
    //private int drawPanel.getHeight();
    private int speedValue;
    private boolean flag;
    /*
     * These variables are used to keep track of 
     * the ball, either it is going LEFT or RIGHT
     * depending on that, we will set the 
     * Co-ordinates.
     */
    private boolean toLeft, toRight;

    private boolean fromTop, fromBottom;

    private Timer timer;

    private JButton button;

    private ActionListener actionTimer; 
    private ActionListener buttonAction;

    MyDraw drawPanel;

    public BallAnimation()
    {
        x = y = count = 0;
        flag = toLeft = false;
        toRight = true;
        fromTop = true;
        fromBottom = false;
        speedValue = 5;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                BallAnimation animation = new BallAnimation();
                animation.go();
            }
        };      
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        /*
         * Class Name : 
         * Java Naming Convention says that class names 
         * should be in Pascal Case, i.e. the first
         * letter of the class name should be capitalized
         * and every new word must start with a capitalized 
         * Alphabet.
         * For Example : 
         * public class ClassName{...}
         * ----------------------------------------------------------
         * Variable Name : 
         * Java Naming Convention says that the variable name
         * should be in Camel Case, i.e. the first letter of 
         * the variable name should be small case or _ (underscore)
         * and every new word must start with a capitalized
         * Alphabet.
         * ---------------------------------------------------------
         */
        drawPanel = new MyDraw(0, 0);
        x = drawPanel.getXValue();
        y = drawPanel.getYValue();
        //contentPane.add(drawPanel);

        actionTimer = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {               
                if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight() 
                            && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y >= drawPanel.getHeight()
                                 && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP LEFT Side
                     * touched the BOTTOM of the JPanel.
                     */
                    y -= speedValue;
                    x += speedValue;
                    fromTop = false;
                    fromBottom = true;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y <= 0
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from BOTTOM LEFT Side
                     * touched the TOP of the JPanel. 
                     */
                    fromTop = true;
                    fromBottom = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    x += speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x >= drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM LEFT Side
                     * touched the RIGHT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = false;
                    toLeft = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }                
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y <= 0
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM RIGHT Side
                     * touched the Top Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    fromTop = true;
                    fromBottom = false;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x <= 0 && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                 && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP RIGHT Side
                     * touched the LEFT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = true;
                    toLeft = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x >= drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && toRight && !toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP LEFT Side
                     * touched the RIGHT Side of the JPanel
                     */
                    toRight = false;
                    toLeft = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y += speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x <= 0 && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the BOTTOM RIGHT Side
                     * touched the LEFT Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    toRight = true;
                    toLeft = false;
                    x += speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (!fromTop && fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y < drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                else if (fromTop && !fromBottom && x < drawPanel.getWidth() && y >= drawPanel.getHeight()
                                  && !toRight && toLeft)
                {
                    /*
                     * Since the ball coming from the TOP RIGHT Side
                     * touched the BOTTOM Side of the JPanel.
                     */
                    fromTop = false;
                    fromBottom = true;
                    x -= speedValue;
                    y -= speedValue;
                }
                System.out.println("X : " + x);
                System.out.println("Y : " + y);
                System.out.println("Direction is LEFT : " + toLeft);
                System.out.println("Direction is RIGHT : " + toRight);
                System.out.println("Coming from TOP : " + fromTop);
                System.out.println("Coming from BOTTOM : " + fromBottom);
                drawPanel.setXYValues(x, y);
            }
        };

        buttonAction = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (!flag)
                {
                    timer.start();
                    button.setText("STOP ANIMATION");
                    flag = true;
                }
                else if (flag)
                {
                    timer.stop();
                    button.setText("START ANIMATION");
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        };

        button = new JButton("START ANIMATION");
        button.addActionListener(buttonAction);

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);        

        timer = new Timer(40, actionTimer);
        System.out.println("WIDTH : " + drawPanel.getWidth());
        System.out.println("HEIGHT : " + drawPanel.getHeight());
    }
    class MyDraw extends JComponent
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private Timer timer;

        public MyDraw(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getXValue()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public int getYValue()
        {
            return y;
        }

        public void setXYValues(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            repaint();
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return (new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I liked this answer though (+1 for that), made things worked for me, but as pointed out by @zebediah49 , my code is crap, as far as logic is concern, so seems like adding function call to it will make it worse, along with the condition check. Thankyou for the kind help on this question :-)

Comment: Today, I changed the logic part of my program, and seems like what you had told in your answer, works too well that no `Listener` sort of thing is needed. What previously I was doing is checking both x and y together, so which led to too much condition check. I separated the two, which resulted in few lines of check, along with your advice worked flawlessly :-) Thankyou for that :-)

Comment: *"changed the logic part of my program"*  Excellent!  Glad to see you took zebediah49's advice (to refactor the logic).  :)

Comment: Yeah, I learned from everywhere :-) , to focus on my logic part from zebediah49, more info about ball thingy from @trashgod and obviously, your suggestion as well, all worked wonders at the end for my small application :-)

Comment: *"I learned from everywhere"*  Everywhere is great.  I'll often do a quick Google & end up at 3 separate threads at SO, getting tidbits from each. ;)

Answer (score 4):

just simply need to [addHierarchyBoundsListener(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addHierarchyBoundsListener%28java.awt.event.HierarchyBoundsListener%29), to your `MyDraw` object, i.e. `drawPanel` , like as explained below :

```
private HierarchyBoundsListener boundsListener = 
                                new HierarchyBoundsListener()
{
    public void ancestorMoved(HierarchyEvent he)
    {
    }

    public void ancestorResized(HierarchyEvent he)
    {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) he.getComponent();
        width = component.getWidth() - 30;
        height = component.getHeight() - 30;
    }
};
```

And to add this to your `drawPanel` object, you be doing :

```
drawPanel.addHierarchyBoundsListener(boundsListener);
```

Comment: This did made my day, adding `HierarchyBoundsListener`. Thankyou for the kind help :-)

Answer (score 2):

I expect you just need to bind some variety of listener (`WindowEventListener`?) to the JFrame, so that `width` and `height` are updated whenever the window dimensions change.

Comment: No, it is better to base the width/height on the current size of the component, as seen in my variant.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, but I'm curious why it's better to fetch it every time you use it?  (Also, why not assign it to a local variable, instead of calling it every time?)

Comment: It is minimal expense to call for the current size, and as the OP noted, the current version does not work when resized.  It might be possible to implement the update of the size using a listener, but it seems a kludgy hack compared to querying the size when it is needed.

Comment: @zebediah49 : Thankyou for pointing out that my code is crap, +1 for that :-) , just it's my first painting thingy, so never bothered that much on it, except for the task in hand which is painting :-) . Thankyou for your kind help on this .